# Handle errors on firebase auth

Tags: flutter

I need to catch and handle errors on my app when an user tries to sing in but I can't achieve that.
How can I solve it?
Here is my code

```
  @override
  Future<void> signInUser(UserEntity user) async {
    try {
      if (user.email!.isNotEmpty && user.password!.isNotEmpty) {
        await firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: user.email!, password: user.password!);
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == "ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND") {
        showToast("user not found");
      } else if (e.code == "INVALID_PASSWORD") {
        showToast("Invalid email or password");
      } else if (e.code == "ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL") {
        showToast("Invalid email");
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is a image of the error
[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by disabling breakpoint all exceptions and change tho code to:

```
  @override
  Future<void> signInUser(UserEntity user) async {
    try {
      if (user.email!.isNotEmpty && user.password!.isNotEmpty) {
        await firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: user.email!,
          password: user.password!,
        );
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      String errorMessage = "An unknown error occurred.";

      switch (e.code) {
        case "user-not-found":
          errorMessage = "User not found.";
          break;
        case "wrong-password":
          errorMessage = "Wrong password.";
          break;
        case "invalid-email":
          errorMessage = "Invalid email.";
          break;
        case "user-disabled":
          errorMessage = "User account is disabled.";
          break;
        case "too-many-request":
          errorMessage = "Too many sign-in attempts. Please try again later.";
          break;
        case "operation-not-allowed":
          errorMessage = "Operation not allowed.";
          break;
        // Add more error codes and their corresponding error messages here.
        default:
          break;
      }
      showToast(errorMessage);
    } catch (e) {
      showToast("An unknown error occurred.");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

// ...

@override
Future<void> signInUser(UserEntity user) async {
  try {
    if (user.email!.isNotEmpty && user.password!.isNotEmpty) {
      await firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: user.email!,
        password: user.password!,
      );
      // Sign-in was successful, you can navigate to the next screen or perform any required actions here.
    }
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    String errorMessage = "An unknown error occurred.";
    switch (e.code) {
      case "ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND":
        errorMessage = "User not found.";
        break;
      case "ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD":
        errorMessage = "Invalid email or password.";
        break;
      case "ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL":
        errorMessage = "Invalid email.";
        break;
      case "ERROR_USER_DISABLED":
        errorMessage = "User account is disabled.";
        break;
      case "ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS":
        errorMessage = "Too many sign-in attempts. Please try again later.";
        break;
      case "ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED":
        errorMessage = "Operation not allowed.";
        break;
      // Add more error codes and their corresponding error messages here.
      default:
        break;
    }
    showToast(errorMessage);
  } catch (e) {
    // Handle other types of exceptions that may occur during sign-in.
    showToast("An unknown error occurred.");
  }
}
```

> If the signInWithEmailAndPassword function is not triggering the
> PlatformException, try using catch (e) instead of on PlatformException
> catch (e) to see if the error can be caught using a general catch
> block.

Comment: None of the options is working. I think is a problem with catch  the error. I edited the question with a image